# Issue with Jquery when making a darkmode

Tags: jquery, css

So I'm making my own portfolio website and I wanted to have a dark mode. So I made one with Jquery. Although I seem to be having quite the problem.

It began with elements in the header not changing colors as I toggled the dark mode. Then I fixed the nav part but I also wanted to change the logo. But it does not work!

**Example**: https://gyazo.com/9fa15d80400efcdb8bc76f770935aa44

The dark mode code is in the master.css

All my code is available **here**:https://github.com/TheBlackVoid/Portfolio

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Your expectation that anyone would clone your repo and dig through its entire contents to find the code you refer to is unrealistic. Please include a **runnable** [mcve] (use the `<>` button). Emphasis on *minimal*. And, to answer your question, it can be achieved in two ways: using a second image for dark mode (and switching `display` property of each `<img>` accordingly) or using an `<svg>` instead of image, with `fill="currentColor"` on the `<path>` element and changing the parent's color. If you provide a **mcve**, I'll provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer:** you have an extra selector when you are trying to grab `.logo` in lines 100 & 101 of about.html

```
    $('header .logo .dark').toggleClass('mode')
    $('header .logo .dark').toggleClass('dark')
```

should just be:

```
    $('header .logo').toggleClass('mode')
    $('header .logo').toggleClass('dark')
```

**Longer Answer:** 
    You shouldn't have to go through and add the classes "mode" & "dark" to everything that you want style in dark mode.

You did start out correctly by toggling the body class:

```
$('body').toggleClass('mode')
$('body').toggleClass('dark')
```

from there, you can do all the rest with just styling 
replace:

```
header nav ul li a:hover.dark,
header nav ul li a.active.dark{
  color: #fff;
  background: #06e89b;
}

header nav ul li a.dark{
  color: #fff;
  background: #141414;
}

header .logo.dark{
  color: #fff;
}
```

with:

```
body.mode.dark header nav ul li a:hover,
body.mode.dark header nav ul li a.active{
  color: #fff;
  background: #06e89b;
}

body.mode.dark header nav ul li a{
  color: #fff;
  background: #141414;
}

body.mode.dark header .logo{
  color: #fff;
}
```